# Is this interface definition valid?

Tags: c#, interface

If you think about interface design rules  Is this interface definition valid?

```
       public interface IS3FileWriter
       {       
           IEnumerable<Amazon.S3Object> ListObjects(string prefix, int maxkeys = 20);       
           void WriteFile(Stream ms, string filePath);
           void DeleteFile(string filePath);
           void CopyFile(string sourcePath, string destinationPath);  
       }
```

Comment: Yes It compiles and works, but this interface design is valid or not?

Answer (score 1):

Personally i dislike your interface

1.Follow methods name convention.For methods they are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw(v=vs.71).aspx).
So rename your method `ListObjects` to `GetListObjects` for example

2.Your interface suggests that it will only write files, but actually it does Copy/Delete/Create operations. So i would rename it to something like `IFileOperations`

3.I don't see how `ListObjects` is connected with files and therefore is inside this interface.


Also default parameter in interface looks suspicious